# Java more than one DB connection in UserTransaction

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, transactions, database-connection, commit

```
static void clean() throws Exception {
  final UserTransaction tx = InitialContext.doLookup("UserTransaction");
  tx.begin();

  try {
    final DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup(Databases.ADMIN);
    Connection connection1 = ds.getConnection();
    Connection connection2 = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement st1 = connection1.prepareStatement("XXX delete records XXX"); // delete data

    PreparedStatement st2 = connection2.prepareStatement("XXX insert records XXX"); // insert new data that is same primary as deleted data above

    st1.executeUpdate();
    st1.close();
    connection1.close();
    st2.executeUpdate();
    st2.close();
    connection2.close();
    tx.commit();
  } finally {
    if (tx.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_ACTIVE) {
      tx.rollback();
    }
  }
}
```

I have a web app, the `DAO` taking `DataSource` as the object to create individual connection to perform database operations.

So I have a `UserTransaction`, inside there are two `DAO` object doing separated action, first one is doing deletion and second one is doing insertion. The deletion is to delete some records to allow insertion to take place because insertion will insert same primary key's data.

I take out the `DAO` layer and translate the logic into the code above. There is one thing I couldn't understand, based on the code above, the insertion operation should fail, because the code (inside the `UserTransaction`) take two different connections, they don't know each other, and the first deletion haven't committed obviously, so second statement (insertion) should fail (due to unique constraint), because two database operation not in same connection, second connection is not able to detect uncommitted changes. But amazingly, it doesn't fail, and both statement can work perfectly.

Can anyone help explain this? Any configuration can be done to achieve this result? Or whether my understanding is wrong?

Comment: You say you have a web app. I suppose it is running in some kind of container? Which one?

Comment: It is running in Weblogic server.

Comment: Could you take a look at the constraints based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39012274/4823977

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your application is running in weblogic server, the java-EE-container is managing the transaction and the connection for you. If you call `DataSource#getConnection` multiple times in a java-ee transaction, you will get multiple `Connection` instances joining the same transaction. Usually those connections connect to database with the identical session. Using oracle you can check that with the following snippet in a `@Stateless` ejb:

```
@Resource(lookup="jdbc/myDS")
private DataSource ds;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="42")
public void testDatasource() throws SQLException {

    try ( Connection con1 = ds.getConnection();
          Connection con2 = ds.getConnection();
        ) {

        String sessId1 = null, sessId2 = null;
        try (ResultSet rs1 = con1.createStatement().executeQuery("select userenv('SESSIONID') from dual") ){
            if ( rs1.next() ) sessId1 = rs1.getString(1);
        };
        try (ResultSet rs2 = con2.createStatement().executeQuery("select userenv('SESSIONID') from dual") ){
            if ( rs2.next() ) sessId2 = rs2.getString(1);
        };

        LOG.log( Level.INFO," con1={0}, con2={1}, sessId1={2}, sessId2={3}"
               , new Object[]{ con1, con2, sessId1, sessId2}
               );
    }

}
```

This results in the following log-Message:

```
con1=com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40@19f32aa, 
con2=com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40@1cb42e0, 
sessId1=9347407, 
sessId2=9347407
```

Note that you get different `Connection` instances with same session-ID.

For more details see eg [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27290901/4308751)

Comment: Thanks! I have been thinking how can I print out the session identity in order to prove whether the connection is same or different, have been looking through `Connection/DataSource` API, none is giving me answer, now I know we have to use SQL to figure out that.

Comment: I presume the `DataSource.getConnetion` is vendor-independent, as in my application is using Weblogic, so the actual behavior should be rely on Weblogic implementation, I read through most of the document from Weblogic, but none I can get the confirmed answer from.

Comment: I just learn a new framework Hibernate, do you know how the `SessionFactory.openSession` and `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession `behave in `Transaction` context and outside of the `Transaction` context?

Comment: I think you should post that as a new SO-Question.

Answer (score 2):

The *only* way to do this properly is to use a transaction manager and two phase commit XA drivers for all databases involved in this transaction.

Comment: `for all databases involved in this transaction`, i only have one database here (Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have autocommit enabled on the connections. This is the default when creating a new connection, as is documented here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

```
System.out.println(connection1.getAutoCommit());
```

will most likely print `true`.

You could try

```
connection1.setAutoCommit(false);
```

and see if that changes the behavior.

In addition to that, it's not really defined what happens if you call close() on a connection and haven't issued a commit or rollback statement beforehand. Therefore it is strongly recommended to either issue one of the two before closing the connection, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()

**EDIT 1:**
If autocommit is false, the it's probably due to the undefined behavior of close. What happens if you switch the statements? :

```
st2.executeUpdate();
st2.close();
connection2.close();
st1.executeUpdate();
st1.close();
connection1.close();
```

**EDIT 2:**
You could also try the "correct" way of doing it:

```
st1.executeUpdate();
st1.close();
st2.executeUpdate();
st2.close();
tx.commit();
connection1.close();
connection2.close();
```

If that doesn't fail, then something is wrong with your setup for UserTransactions.

Comment: I printed out the value, `AutoCommit` is false, any connection obtained within `UserTransaction` should be false.

Comment: Amended my answer as AutoCommit is false.

Comment: Have you checked the answere here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39012274/4823977 ? Could you add the DB version etc?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database this is quite a normal case.

An object implementing `UserTransaction` interface represents a "logical transaction". It doesn't always map to a real, "physical" transaction that a database engine respects.
For example, there are situations that cause *implicit commits* (as well as *implicit starts*) of transactions. In case of Oracle (can't vouch for other DBs), closing a connection is one of them.

[From Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/getsta.htm):

> "If the auto-commit mode is disabled and you close the connection
>   without explicitly committing or rolling back your last changes, then
>   an implicit COMMIT operation is run".

But there can be other possible reasons for implicit commits: select for update, various locking statements, DDLs, and so on. They are database-specific.

So, back to our code.
The first transaction is committed by closing a connection.
Then another transaction is implicitly started by the DML on the second connection. It inserts non-conflicting changes and the second `connection.close()` commits them without PK violation. `tx.commit()` won't even get a chance to commit anything (and how could it? the connection is already closed).

The bottom line: *"logical" transaction managers* don't always give you the full picture.
Sometimes transactions are started and committed without an explicit reason. And sometimes they are even ignored by a DB.

PS: I assumed you used Oracle, but the said holds true for other databases as well. For example, [MySQL's list of implicit commit reasons](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

Comment: Yup, I am using Oracle database. I try to write a simple code, to throw out error after an insert (follow by connection close), the insertion can be successfully rollback, if not wrong, `close` will not close the connection immediately, it will delegate the closing to the transaction manager to handle.

Comment: So quite sure, there is no such implicit commit in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If auto-commit mode is disabled and you close the connection
without explicitly committing or rolling back your last changes,
then an implicit `COMMIT` operation is executed.

Please check below link for details:

http://in.relation.to/2005/10/20/pop-quiz-does-connectionclose-result-in-commit-or-rollback/